# What is the difference between several alloc methods of memory in c++?

Tags: c++

> What is the difference between several alloc methods of  memory in c++?

like *so* new, malloc and so on ...

thx

Comment: Information about each is pretty easy to find, as well as what happens when you mix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**malloc** allocates uninitialized memory. Malloc is not `type safe`

**new** initializes the allocated memory by calling the constructor. Also new keyword is `type safe`

**delete** is used to deallocate memory from the heap.

**NOTE:-** `new` and `delete` are C++ specific features.

Besides many other point which you may want to see. Here is one point which is [worth reading](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/heap.html#fqa-16.4)

> [16.4] Why should I use new instead of trustworthy old malloc()?
>
> FAQ: new/delete call the constructor/destructor; new is type safe,
>   malloc is not; new can be overridden by a class.
>
> FQA: The virtues of new mentioned by the FAQ are not virtues, because
>   constructors, destructors, and operator overloading are garbage (see
>   what happens when you have no garbage collection?), and the type
>   safety issue is really tiny here (normally you have to cast the void*
>   returned by malloc to the right pointer type to assign it to a typed
>   pointer variable, which may be annoying, but far from "unsafe").
>
> Oh, and using trustworthy old malloc makes it possible to use the
>   equally trustworthy & old realloc. Too bad we don't have a shiny new
>   operator renew or something.
>
> Still, new is not bad enough to justify a deviation from the common
>   style used throughout a language, even when the language is C++. In
>   particular, classes with non-trivial constructors will misbehave in
>   fatal ways if you simply malloc the objects. So why not use new
>   throughout the code? People rarely overload operator new, so it
>   probably won't get in your way too much. And if they do overload new,
>   you can always ask them to stop.

Comment: More accurately, `new` default-initializes or value-initializes it, or even uses an initial value, depending on how you use it. That's not the only difference, though, and there are more allocation methods than those two.

Comment: Why malloc is not type safe?